# How can I set up multiple storage accounts and one custom domain on Microsoft Azure CDN

Tags: azure, azure-cdn

I have recently decided to venture into the world of Azure.. I have stumbled at the 1st stage really. Here is what I have done to date:

1). I created a CDN Profile and configured this using default settings.
2). I created 2 storage accounts (one called 'css' and one called 'images')
3). I created a CDN endpoint - and picked 'images' storage account as 'origin hostname'.

This is where I get stuck as I can browse and see images on the CDN endpoint URL, however I cannot see how to use the same custom domain for the 'css' storage account?

In essence I am trying to have 1 custom domain (eg. cdn.mysite.com) and be able to use 'cdn.mysite.com/css/blobname' and 'cdn.mysite.com/images/blobname' to get my images and css files respectively.

Is this possible? Or m I over complicating things and should have just one storage account with all my images and css fiels in it?

thanks - still have 27 days of trial to go before I try something else!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are definitely over complicating things! There is no need for separate storage accounts, at least not until you are having significant performance issues, at which case, for images and css, you've likely got bigger issues.

Simply have a single storage account, with that folder structure defined.

Comment: Thanks Michael - your opening line made me review what i'd done and I think this is correct:

1 x Storage Account with multiple blob containers.

Just waiting for DNS to propagate and then its fingers crossed..